# What is needed to determine the Faraday tensor?

Tags: tensor-calculus, maxwell-equations

What data is needed to determine the Faraday tensor and how is it done?

The Maxwell equation seems coupled to the Faraday tensor and the four-current (which seems coupled to either the charge distribution and the charges' four-current or the charge distribution and the charge current?). The Lorentz force law seems coupled to the time derivative of the four-momenta (which seems coupled to the mass distribution and the mass' four velocity) and the charge density and the Faraday tensor and the mass' four velocity.

Perhaps one needs a constitutive equation between the faraday tensor and all the input at a given time as well.

Have I missed something or is this enough to determine the Faraday tensor at a given time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve the Maxwell's equations

$$\text dF = 0$$
$$\text dG = J$$

for a given PDE problem (von Neumann/Dirichlet).

The second one is the constitutive equation since it links the Faraday tensor to the 4-current density $J$ via its Hodge-dual $G=\star F$.

Comment: So the connection to charges and currents come from the second equation, and the first one just constrains the allowed solutions? Do I not need the Lorentz force law as well? To couple it to other forces that work on masses? That should constrain it more?

Comment: The meaning of those two equation is the same as Maxwell's equations. You need them all to determine the electric and magnetic field, and hence the Faraday tensor. Lorentz force arises as an interaction between the "Faraday field" and any external charges in it so it doesn't constrain solutions.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Is not the lorentz force valid for the particles that was used to compute the faraday tensor? Do one need to compute $n$ faraday tensor fields for $n$ particles (each one has one particle removed, the one that will be used in the lorentz force computation)?

Comment: One usually consider the effect of an existing electromagnetic field over an external charge, without taking into account the charge's contribution. In fact, for a point-like charge, these contributions would be infinite (self-interaction).

Comment: Bummer... I would really like to find how one could tackle that issue. "perturbative", "renormalization", "near zone", "far zone" seems to come at top in google, do you have tips for more words to search for?

Comment: Is the solution to that perhaps QED (perhaps it is time I try to study it :)) Or do one separate the system into charges in an external field in that as well?

Comment: The same idea applies to QED. The quantum theory brings in some extra nuisances, like self-interaction, which is now a thing that pops up from perturbative theory, which requires renormalisation. However, you can still link the classical self-interaction with the quantum one to some extent. I think Feynman gives a nice discussion on the topic in his series of Lectures on Physics.